# How can I search across multiple tables(models) with Sunspot Solr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, solr, sunspot

I want users to be able to use one search box to search for different objects. I would differentiate them on the results page. Both would be full text search.

Should I make a Search controller and load everything into the index action with something like:

```
@posts = Post.all
@groups = Group.all
```

Something tells me that would be fantastically inefficient.

I'm not really sure where to start, I haven't managed to find anything addressing this question on the interwebs, but if I have overlooked something let me know.

Thanks

EDIT:
here's my search bar that is available globally on my website:

```
    -form_tag posts_path, :method => :get do
     =text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'searchfield'
     =submit_tag '',:name => nil, :id => 'searchbutton'
```

it only searches the "Post" model right now, and displays the results on the Post#index view

I want to be able to have queries typed into the search box be searched for in both the Post and Group tables, and the results be displayed in two separate columns on the same page. maybe through a search controller/view

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Show results in two columns? Show them in series first groups, second posts? Show them in order of relevance ?

Comment: edited with code to explain what I meant. I want results to be displayed in two columns, each corresponding to the type of object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the searchable directive from sunspot solr to your models for indexing. For example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :body
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :name
  end
end
```

If you have existing data in DB make sure to run `rake sunspot:solr:reindex` for indexing. For new data the indexing will be done in a hook.

Now you can search:

```
@posts = Post.search {fulltext params[:search]}
@groups = Group.search {fulltext params[:search]}
```

Now you have the data for your two columns.

Comment: but if there is one search bar, let's say a user types in "roller skates" how do I run that search in both tables simultaneously?

Comment: should I make a Search controller? Right now the `@posts = Post.seach {fulltext params[:search]` is being conducted in Post#index action, so when I try to add in `@groups = Group.search {fulltext params[:search]` it doesn't work

Comment: it keeps giving me the error `undefined method 'model_name' for Sunspot::Search::StandardSearch:Class` I'm running it through a search controller now. Both Post and Group have been made 'searchable'

Comment: GOT IT! I had to use a different format, instead of : `@posts = Post.search {fulltext params[:search]}` etc... I had to do `@search = Post.search do{ fulltext params[:search]} end @posts = @search.results`

Comment: Thanks for your help clyfe! You galvanized me into finding a solution, I really appreciate it. Happy holidays

Comment: This solution will make two calls to the sunspot server and two calls to database. knowuh's answer below is preferable.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to search both types at once, you can use this form:

```
# Pass your models in by class constant
Sunspot.search(Post,Group) do |s| 
    s.fulltext(params[:search])
end
```

This is documented in the wiki:
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Working-with-search#initiating-a-search

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but I found something useful. It is a gem that helps you searching across multiple tables:

https://github.com/toptierlabs/acts_as_fulltextable.

It helps you keeping all the searchable data (from different models) in one place.